# 'variable length array in structure' error in NDK

Tags: android, c++, arrays, clang++

I want to make a POC of c++ / android with NDK (and Clang ...)
Unfortunately, I'm stuck with VLAIS error. I saw a lot of questions about this but can't find a workaround  (with vector for example ...)

It seems that gcc is obsolete for NDK, I'm stuck with Clang.

my code:

```
void upload_data(UINT_32 addr, char *buff, INT_32 mark, UINT_32 buff_size)
{
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) packet_struct        
{
    UINT_32 packet_data;
   char     my_data[buff_size];      <------Clang Error             
} packet;


packet.packet_data = 0;
memcpy(packet.my_data, buff, buff_size);

(...)
 }
```

Could someone help me convert my code ? 
thanks

Comment: VLAs are not part of C++ (they are allowed in C).  Try moving this code to a `.c` file and calling it from your C++ code.

Comment: Is `buff_size` known at compile time ?

Comment: I m stuck with clang on NDK. I tried c and c++, same error with clang. Buff_size is variable